# How to derive continuous-time Linear Quadratic Gaussian state estimator?

Tags: stochastic-processes, control-theory, optimal-control, quadratic-programming, parameter-estimation

In a Linear Quadratic Gaussian problem, one can prove a separation principle, thereby separating the objective of control design from state estimation, when the linear system has process and measurement noise. The [continuous-time solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear%E2%80%93quadratic%E2%80%93Gaussian_control) involves solving for two dual Riccati differential equations for controller and state estimator, respectively.

Most of the papers and lectures I've read spend a lot of time proving the separation principle, as well as the optimality of the linear feedback. However, maybe it's a limitation in my understanding, I don't see any proof/derivation of how the **continuous-time** state estimator relates to the process/measurement noise covariances and the Riccati equation. The discrete-time variant, specifically Kalman Filter, proof is aplenty, but I don't like to rely on any discussion in discrete-time.

Even more to the basic, I would like to understand precisely even the problem formulation of the continuous-time LQG state estimator. What is it trying to minimize, and what are the "manipulated variables"? (i.e. what is the cost function?)

Comment: The stochastic version of the separation principle is, I believe, not hard to find in textbooks. I find the references in the Wikipedia article "Separation principle in stochastic control" to be fairly complete.

I am not knowledgeable about a full presentation of the deterministic version. The term "separation principle" is often applied to a weaker statement concerning the eigenvalues of the closed-loop system. There are fewer references on the deterministic Kalman filter, which include the text Mathematical Control Theory : Deterministic Finite Dimensional Systems by Eduardo D Sontag.

Comment: @Pait The deterministic version in continuous-time is simply the Kalman Decomposition. The separation principle in stochastic system is also widely available (in continuous and discrete time). However, I have yet to find a reference that discusses the "continuous Kalman filter". Most texts simply reference Kalman filter, and swiftly move on to the LQG control assuming the observation problem is solved.

Comment: Yes, the usual deterministic version is the Kalman decomposition, weaker than the separation principle of the stochastic version. It's a gap in the literature, I think.

The continuous-time version is often called the Kalman-Bucy filter. It's a full analog of the discrete time, except for the distinction between the prediction and update steps of discrete-time Kalman filtering, which is said not to exist in continuous time.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Pait's comment, I've found my answer in the [Kalman-Bucy filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Kalman%E2%80%93Bucy_filter). To answer my latter questions, an optimal linear state estimator has two objectives:

- Ensure that the state estimates are unbiased ($E[e(t)-\hat{e}(t)]=0$)
- Minimize the variance of the state estimation error

By restricting the state estimation to linear in nature, objective #1 automatically confers the Luenberger observer structure (all time-varying):

$$\dot{x}(t)=Ax+Bu+L(y-C\hat{x})$$

Then, given a symmetric positive-definite matrix, $M(t)$, we can construct a cost function as:

$$J=E[(x-\hat{x})M(t)(x-\hat{x})^T]=tr[M(t)P(t)]$$

where $P(t)=E[(x-\hat{x})(x-\hat{x})^T]$ is the state estimate error covariance matrix.

Objective #2 is then re-stated to minimize the cost function, $J$, by selecting the Kalman gain, $L(t)$. It is then possible to show that the optimal solution involves solving for the Riccati equation for $P(t)$, then use it to set the optimal Kalman gain.

The full derivation can be found in [Athens, Tse, *A direct derivation of the optimal linear filter using the maximum principle*, 1967.](https://www.ece.rutgers.edu/%7Egajic/pdffiles/519KalmanFiltering/Lecture4b.pdf), which is well-written and easy to follow.

Comment: JZYL: Could you explain how the setup is different from the regular KF ? Is that because the observation equation is deterministic ( i.e. no error term ) ? Thanks.